# Use a modifier key to modify file association

Tags: ubuntu, bash, file-association, modifier-keys

When watching a movie on a laptop, it should cleverly disable its screen:

- If no external screen is plugged, don't disable.
- If a modifier key is used to open the movie, don't disable.
- If an external screen is plugged and no modifier is used, disable the laptop screen.
- When the media player exits, restore the laptop screen.

I've written the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$(cat /sys/class/drm/card0-VGA-1/status)" = connected ]
then
  xrandr --output eDP1 --off
  vlc "$1"
  while [ "$(pidof vlc)" > 0 ]
  do
    sleep 1
  done
  xrandr --output eDP1 --auto --below VGA1
else
  vlc "$1"
fi
```

eDP1 represents the laptop screen, VGA1 the external screen. The script is used by associating movie files in `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` with the following desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=VLC
Comment=
Exec=path/to/the/above/script
Icon=vlc
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
```

Can you suggest a way to modify the script or the desktop file, or any other way to check for a modifier key - the only restriction being that a single action must be used to open the movie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be no off-the-shelf solution. However, it is not difficult to use Xlib and Xkb directly.

Create a file `getmodkey.c`:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/XKBlib.h>

int main() {
    XkbStateRec r;
    Display* d = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    XkbGetState(d, XkbUseCoreKbd, &r);
    printf("mod: 0x%x\n", r.mods);
    XCloseDisplay(d);
    return !( r.mods & 1 );
}
```

and compile it with `-lX11`, for example

```
make LDLIBS="-lX11" getmodkey
```

The exit status code of the program would be `0` if the Shift-key was pressed, `1` otherwise. To test for a different modifier, adjust the `(r.mods & keymask)` condition (the mask for Shift is 1).

Then, this program should be easy to integrate,

```
if getmodkey; then 
  echo "shift!"
else
  echo "no shift"
fi
```

Comment: I'll look at it later today, but I wanted to thank you in the meantime.